# Union between linked servers sql

Tags: sql-server

SSMS is saying there is an error at UNION of the below sql query. I cant find the problem.

```
begin try
    SELECT * FROM cnbahirdar.CERP_CN_Bahirdar.dbo.vw_hrmsPayrollTransactionBI
    end try
begin catch
    select NULL
end catch
UNION ALL
begin try
    SELECT * FROM cnwoldiya.CERP_CN_Weldiya.dbo.vw_hrmsPayrollTransactionBI
    end try
begin catch
    select NULL
end catch
```

The code looks correct but couldnt run it sql

Comment: Code is incorrect. try...catch and UNION ALL  -too much. Do not be lazy  -specify only required fields in the select

Comment: the select statement fetches only fields that are selected in the view. can you point me where the error is. the views are in linked servers that are remote. Thank you

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: What error? Show us the error message.

Comment: You can't use `try/catch` in the middle of a query. `UNION ALL` doesn't combine two independent queries, it's part of a single query.

Comment: *"The code looks correct but couldnt run it SQL"* It doesn't look correct at all. YOu can't just dump logical flow operators, like `TRY..CATCH`, `IF`, `GOTO`, etc, in the middle of a statement. If we add some statement terminators into your query (which you should always be adding) you'll see what the problem is: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/L2C8dQ9S)

Comment: Also do the objects `cnbahirdar.CERP_CN_Bahirdar.dbo.vw_hrmsPayrollTransactionBI` and `cnwoldiya.CERP_CN_Weldiya.dbo.vw_hrmsPayrollTransactionBI` only have *one* column? If so, why use `*`? If not, what do you think a `UNION ALL` of many columns to a data set of a single `NULL` column is going to do  but error? The datasets in each `UNION`ed query *must* have the same number of columns. `SELECT 1,2 UNION ALL SELECT 3` will generate an error, as the bottom dataset has a different number of columns to the top dataset.